# SQL translating two rows from one table with another

Tags: sql

I am quite new to SQL and am having problems with the following. My actual problem is quite complex but the below example crystalises the problem I have.

Imagine two tables as follows:-

Table 1

```
|Name | ID1 | ID2 |
--------------------
| xxx | 1  |  1   |
--------------------
| yyy | 3  |  1   |
--------------------
| zzz | 2  |  1   |
```

Table 2

```
| ID | Desc |
--------------
| 1  | aaa  |
-------------
| 2  | bbbb |
--------------
| 3  | ccc  |
```

The meaning of both numbers in ID1 and ID2 in Table 1 are given by the description in Table 2.

As I understand the following query would allow me to use the description rather than the ID for ID1 in Table1 in the where clause:

```
SELECT name
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
     Table2
     ON Table.ID1 = Table2.ID
where Table2.Desc = 'aaa';
```

but what I can't work out is a way of specifying it so that I can access both ID1 and ID2 simultaneously in the where clause by the description defined in Table2.

I can't help feeling that this must be a pretty standard proceedure but can't work it out.

Any suggestions are most welcome

Silas

Answer (score 0):

First, it is generally a bad idea to store two ids in two different columns.  Sometimes it is ok, but normally you want a junction table with one row per name and id.

Another way to write your query is using `EXISTS`.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Table1 t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table2 t2
              WHERE t2.id IN (t.id1, t.id2) AND t2.Desc = 'aaa'
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this?

```
SELECT name
FROM 
    Table1 t
    INNER JOIN Table2 t1
    ON t.ID1 = t1.ID
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t.ID2 = t2.ID
WHERE 
    t1.Desc = 'aaa'
AND t2.Desc = 'ccc';
```